Attemp to install unwanted program
IS THIS NORMAL? In google chrome I get a popup window asking permission to send a report. If i answer yes i get another window asking comfirmation with my password. Im afraid someone is trying to install something.

We can't see what you see.  What addons do you have installed?  Is it on all pages or a specific page?  Can you screenshot EXACTLY what you're seeing about "popup window"?

It happens 1 or 2 times a night; Next time i will take a screenshot and post it.

Are you taking about a crash report? Please edit your question and add the screenshot.

So far everything is normal. I didnt get those massages anymore. Thank you.
